# Where should I start? (piano)

Tags: piano

I am a returning player. The most I've dove into piano was learning the Treble Clef, Bass Clef, the notes, keys, and different Key Signatures.

I was only able to play songs in the C & G Major Scales. Although I was able to play every major scale up to 2 octaves with both hands simultaneously.

I never owned a full size piano / keyboard, however a gracious friend was generous enough to gift me his.

-> I would kind of like to start from ground zero if possible.

Any music majors / professors have any advice on where to start? What resources could a minimum wage worker use to start learning the piano again.

Any advice is welcome~ Thank-you very much in advance.

Comment: The main advice you are likely to get is "find a good teacher".

Comment: @ToddWilcox - you beat me (and many others) to it!

Comment: I think this is essentially the same question as the linked duplicate.  If you have anything more specific to ask, please feel free to post another question!

Answer (score 0):

A adult beginners book would be a good starting place to get going again.

If the cost of lessons is not too much than of course a teacher would help immensely.

Piano lessons online : https://www.hoffmanacademy.com/

coursera.org still offers some great resources for free or paid, probably better for music theory etc.

https://www.coursera.org/courses?languages=en&query=music

As a private instruction teacher I always tell my students not to let things hold them back if they want to learn, so find any of these resources and just get to work.

Comment: Regarding adult beginner books..  I'm using the Alfred Adult Piano Course http://a.co/ac51cm